# qt5 mac os dyld: Library not loaded:

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, qt5

I try to make python GUI apps. So I install QT Creator but when I run an empty project. I get this error.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../.Python
  Referenced from: /Users/melihozkan/Desktop/Projects/tgenv/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
```

Hpw can I solve this ? And with Anaconda, what should I do for develop GUI apps in python?

Comment: I solved this issue by changing python interpreter to anaconda